# Angular Universal jQuery is not defined, JQuery(function) is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, angular6, angular-universal

I have implemented angular universal in my project, everything works fine

package versions:

> "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
>
> "jquery": "^3.3.1",

I am using `ngx-slick` which is using JQuery internally, after running the build on server I am getting the below error

```
ERROR ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at /Users/vikash.patel/gthub/gt-hub-web-app/dist/server.js:511098:13
```

to remove  `jQuery is not defined,` I found a solution that to declare this

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery'
    })
```

in webpack.server.config.js

or by declaring global variable in server.ts file

after declaring this I am getting the below error

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.$instance.slick is not a function
    at /Users/vikash.patel/gthub/gt-hub-web-app/dist/server.js:511105:29
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: There is a patch for that, waiting to be merged: https://github.com/devmark/ngx-slick/compare/master...vn271:patch-1. Meanwhile, maybe you can specifically not add that lib in your server build?

Comment: thanks for your response. yes, your above solution will work.